# P-Channel MOSFET Stays Conductive When Above 11 V

Tags: microcontroller, mosfet, stm32, p-channel

I recently assembled a custom PCB which includes a P-channel MOSFET circuit to switch on and off 12 V loads. It is able to switch up to 11 V, but once the input voltage is above that the output stays high even when the circuit is driven low by the STM32F103 microcontroller.

The driver NPN transistor is the BC846AWHE3-TP [Digikey](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/micro-commercial-co/BC846AWHE3-TP/16718450) and the P-channel MOSFET is the DMP26M7UFG-7 [Digikey](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/diodes-incorporated/DMP26M7UFG-7/5267940)

U9 is a current sensor IC.

Below are images of my schematic and board layout.

[image: Schematic]
[image: Board Layout]

Comment: Your schematics and layout don't match.  All the reference designators are different.

Comment: @SteKulov thanks for pointing this out, I have updated the photo

Comment: What is U9? You have to show what is feeding the MOSFET.

Comment: @Unimportant U9 is a current sensor IC.

Comment: The absolute maximum gate-source voltage (Vgss) for the DMP26M7UFG is ±10 V. Once your supply goes above 11 V, you're exceeding that.

Comment: @DaveTweed Ah I see the issue. Is there any way of fixing this without redesigning? Maybe making it so when the transistor drives low it doesn't create a Vgss above +- 10v?

Comment: _”any way of fixing this without redesigning”_ Your circuit does not work as its supposed to but you want to keep it as-is?

Comment: @winny Without redesigning and reordering the board.

Comment: The simplest fix would be to lift the emitter of Q9 and insert a resistor between it and ground. This turns it into a current sink. You want it to sink no more than 1 mA through R27, so the resistance value depends on the maximum voltage on `MOSFET3`. For example, if this voltage is 3.3 V, you select an emitter resistor that's no less than (3.3V - 0.6V)/1 mA = 2700 Ω.

Comment: @DaveTweed by lift the emitter what do you mean? Does that mean to tie it to 3.3v instead of 12v like it currently is?

Comment: "Lift" simply means disconnect it from ground so that you can insert the series resistor.

Comment: How about finding another PMOS with higher VGS rating but the same footprint?